# Не получается с помощью mockito подменить вызов метода

Tags: spring, mockito

Пытаюсь с помощью mockito подменить вызов метода. Код сильно упростил, чтобы уменьшить его.
Имеется сервис

```
@Service
public class CalService {
  public int addI(int input1) {
    return 0;
  }
  public Integer addAttr(DataAtributes attr) {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

объект

```
public class DataAtributes {
  Integer number;
  String name;
  public DataAtributes(Integer number, String name) {
    this.number = number;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

и еще один класс, который вызывает метод из CalService

```
@Component
public class GetCalcService {
  @Autowired
  private CalService calService ;
  DataAtributes dataAtributes;
  public Integer setCalc() {
    dataAtributes = new DataAtributes(1,"test");
    Integer val = calService.addAttr(dataAtributes);
    return val;
  }
}
```

и сам класс тестирования

```
@SpringBootTest
public class CaclServisTest {
  @Mock
  CalService calcService;
  @InjectMocks
  GetCalcService getCalcService ;

  @Test
  void add() {
    DataAtributes dataAtributes = new DataAtributes(1,"test");
    when(calcService.addAttr(dataAtributes)).thenReturn(57);
    Integer calc = getCalcService .setCalc();
    log.info("calc = " + calc);
  }
}
```

Если я подменяю метод с примитивным типом (addI), то все работает. А вот код приведенный выше вызывает родной метод, а не подмененный, в результате в переменной calc  получаю 0, вместо 57.
Я так понимаю, что причина в том, что объекты dataAtributes в качестве параметра метода разные.
Но как это победить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае проблема возникает из-за того, что в `DataAttributes` нет правильного метода `equals` и `mockito` не знает, что объект, который вы сконфигурировали в тесте равен тому, что передает `GetCalcService`.

`mockito` использует `equals` для сравнения, а с точки зрения `equals` объекты не равны.

Определите `equals` в `DataAttributes`.

Альтернативный вариант (когда для типа не имеет смысла определять equals, или в тесте нужна особая логика при конфигурации мока) это воспользоваться `ArgumentMatcher`:

```
public class DataAttributesMatcher implements ArgumentMatcher<DataAttributes> {

    private DataAttributes left;

    public DataAttributesMatcher(DataAttributes value) {
       this.left = value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(DataAttributes right) {
        return left.number.equals(right.number) &&
          left.name.equals(right.name);
    }
}

// и в тесте
when(calcService.addAttr(
   argThat(new DataAttributesMatcher(dataAtributes)))).thenReturn(57);
```

В этом случае вместо `equals` будет использоваться логика сравнения из определенного вами `ArgumentMatcher`-а. Так же есть возможность [использования macher-ов](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.18/org/mockito/hamcrest/MockitoHamcrest.html) из hamcrest.

Comment: Я определил Equals и HashCode в DataAttributes. Использовал предложенный IDEA вариант по умолчанию. Не помогает, mockito  все равно считает их разными. Что вы имелии ввиду под правильным equals ? Может я не правильно его определяю?

Comment: Убедитесь, что у вас mock вообще используется в сервисе. Я дополнил ответ, как правильно мокать бины в интеграционном тесте.

Comment: Использую именно MockBean. Сам mock работает, но я сделал вот как: вынес в отдельный метод получение dataAtributes и в тесте его также мокаю и в итоге получаю один объект, что в коде что в тесте. Который уже используется для следующего мока calcService.addAttr(dataAtributes). Вот так все работает, а если получаю реальный объект dataAtributes, то метод addAttr уже не мокается и Equals и HashCode почему то не помогают. Не пойму почему

Comment: Причем я проверил в дебаге HashCode  у этих объектов совпадают

Comment: У вас в вопросе код совсем другой :) Мой ответ относится к коду в вопросе. Я не могу догадаться почему у вас не работает, если код вы поменяли.

Comment: Нет, я просто описал как решил свой вопрос не используя ArgumentMatcher, а теперь возникла аналогичная ситуация, но наверно вы правы надо было создать новый вопрос